Inserting a widget inside a specific cell inside a QTableView
I want custom widget inside a specific cell of the QTableView
I have test code,
Which has a QTableview with these properties

Custom header for each column
Only one row getting selected at a time
Selected row should be non editable

I want to add a button to the last column of each row.
Saw this post PyQt. How to insert a widget in a QTableView
TableModel class and QStandardItemModel seem to be different how do I make this happen?
I am new to pyqt so would i detailed explanation
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView,QTableWidgetItem,QHeaderView

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287713/how-can-you-set-header-labels-for-qtableview-columns
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.columns = ["A","B","C","D"]
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # return f"Column {section + 1}"
            return self.columns[section]
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return f"{section + 1}"

    def setWidgets():
        setIndexWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table.verticalHeader().show()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().show()
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.table.pressed.connect(self.onClicked) 
        self.table.clicked.connect(self.onClickedI) 
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        data = [
          [4, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [7, 8, 9],
        ]
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.header = self.table.horizontalHeader()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
    def onClicked(self,r):
        print(r.row()," ",r.column())
    def onClickedI(self,r):
        print(r.row()," ",r.column())


app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()


The method to set the widgets does not belong in the model. setIndexWidget() must be used on the view, and the model should have no knowledge of the view. If you want the widgets to show, or interact with, data from the model, you should use a delegate but that's not easy for beginners.

Your TableModeand QStandardItemModel are different just in their internal implementation, but their *interface* is completely identical as they are both Qt item models (inheriting from the base QAbstractItemModel) which are only data structures that are and should always be completely independent from anything related to the UI. Simplifying, they're similarly to other data structures like python lists: alist()object *contains* other objects, it's not able to *show* buttons. The post you link already explains what to do: callsetIndexWidget()using theindex(row, column)` of the model.

For instance, in your case, self.table.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(0, 2), QPushButton()) will add a button to the cell in the first row (0) at the third column (2). If you want to apply that to all rows, just use a basic for row in range(len(data)): and replace the arguments of index() above with the row of the for loop and using the index of the last column (eg. len(data[0]) - 1). I strongly suggest you to patiently study the official Qt Model/View Programming guide.
